# Display Lightning Details record data

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I currently have a Lightning app that displays a list of custom Master object records. They are displayed like so

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="ListWhiteboardItemsApexController">

<aura:attribute name="whiteboardItems" type="Whiteboard_Item__c[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.whiteboardItems}" var="whiteboardItem">  
        <c:whiteboardItem whiteboardItem="{!whiteboardItem}" "/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Each of Master records can have many details records attached to it. I want to displayed all the detail records associated with each Master record. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper class accordingly to store the related records of each master records and display in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Related list is not supported in Lightning Components, you might need to create separate tabs within your component.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle that in the server-controller and parse the response for that server call... something like:

```
var action = component.get("c.getWhiteboardItems");
action.setParams({whiteBoardId : id});
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
           component.set("v.whiteboardItems", response.getReturnValue());
        }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```